# Add new item in dropdownlist by getting id from dropdownlist object in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using the following code :

```
 var objSelect = $(this).parent().parent().find("select");

                                var mySelect = $(objSelect).attr('id'); //getting id from object of dropdownlist
                                var myOptions = {
                                    val: 'test',
                                };
                                $.each(myOptions, function (val, text) {
                                    mySelect.append(
    $('<option selected="selected"></option>').val(val).html(text)
);
                                });
```

The above code not able to add new item in dropdownlist.But if i am using :

```
 var objSelect = $(this).parent().parent().find("select");

                                var mySelect = $('#str_anodshape');//Directly giving id of dropdownlist
                                var myOptions = {
                                    val: 'test',
                                };
                                $.each(myOptions, function (val, text) {
                                    mySelect.append(
    $('<option selected="selected"></option>').val(val).html(text)
);
                                });
```

then i able to add item.

**Problem :**

As you can see in the above code i am not able to add new item in dropdownlist when i get id of dropdownlist from **objSelect**.

Comment: if you have the id of the `select` why don't you use it? Take into account that repeated ids are not valid so if you have several elements with id `str_anodshape` you'll have to change that.

Comment: Is `mySelect.append` a c&p error? You'd have to to `.append` to `objSelect`, not the attribute string you got from there.

Comment: Actually this javascript function is common for 13 forms and each page have dropdowns with unique id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do this:

```
$('#' + mySelect).append($('<option selected="selected"></option>').val(val).html(text));
```

because you just saved the id as a String and no jQuery-Object

Answer (score 0):

*Your first scenario:*

```
var objSelect = $(this).parent().parent().find("select");
var mySelect = $(objSelect).attr('id');
```

Here `mySelect` is acting on not one object but a set of objects. This is because you are selecting all "*select*" elements. The second line will simply get the `id` of first element of the set. This `id` is string and you cannot append to a string.

*Your second scenario:*

```
var objSelect = $(this).parent().parent().find("select");
var mySelect = $('#str_anodshape');
```

Here `mySelect` is one object (bcoz you are selecting it with id, assuming you have unique ids). `objSelect` is immaterial here.

*If you change the first scenario with:*

```
var objSelect = $(this).parent().parent().find("select").first();
objSelect.append.....
```

Then it will work because it will then get the first element in the set as one object on which you can do manipulation(s).